# How do I format given content in CSV format?

Tags: regex

I am learning Regular Expression and need some help. I would appreciate it if someone can help me get this going, please. I have about 500 records in a text file in this format:

```
"1",
"avatar",
"Fox Studios",
"2,782.3",
"760.5",
"27.3%",
"2,021.8",
"72.7%",
"2009",


"2",
"titanic",
"Paramount",
"2,186.8",
"658.7",
"30.1%",
"1,528.1",
"69.9%",
"1997",


"3",
"The Avengers",
"Disney/Buena Vista Studios",
"1,518.6",
"623.4",
"41.0%",
"895.2",
"59.0%",
"2012",
```

I would like to have these records formatted in CSV format. I am using Notepad++. My thoughts are to:

Earch record has three [\r\n] between except the very first record. 
Can I count do an expression where if a line has three [\n\r] then treat it as a new record

I googled and found quite a few expressions but didn't have much success. I "CNTRL+F" within notepad++ and did find and replace:

```
find: [\r\n]+
replace: <blank>
```

which pull all the records on to one single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have googled is already spot on. Just use a quantifier to say you want the linebreak characters three times. Depending on your OS (or rather the files line endings), you need to modify it.

```
Windows: (\r\n){3}
Unix:    \n{3}
Mac:     \r{3}
```

Set the replace to: {\n}

Then do the search/replace in the whole file.

[See here](http://regex101.com/r/iC0gY8) for an explanation of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `awk` if you do not actually want to solve it with `grep`

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS ="\n\n\n"; FS="\n"} {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9 }' yourdata.txt
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS ="\n\n\n"; FS="\n"} {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9 }' yourdata.txt > yourdata.cvs
```

`RS` -> the record separator; `FS` -> field separator; `$n` -> field #n